# Cannot DELETE mongodb entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a blog app using node.js/express/mongoose/mongodb. I am creating a delete route so I can delete posts from my admin panel. I am also using method-override to delete. Whenever I press the button I created to delete a post I am met with an error saying cannot DELETE blogs/(blog name here). Not sure why it is not working, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Delete route code

```
//DELETE BLOG ROUTE
app.delete("/blogs/:slug", function(req, res){
  //DESTROY BLOG
  Blog.findOneAndRemove({ slug: req.params.slug}, function(err){
      if(err){
          res.redirect("/admin");
      } else {
          res.redirect("/admin");
      }
  })
});
```

Here is my button to delete on my admin panel

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <a href="/blogs/<%= blog.slug %>" class="btn btn-primary">View Post</a>
                                    <a href="/blogs/<%= blog.slug%>/edit" class="btn btn-success">Edit Post</a>
                                    <form action="/blogs/<%= blog.slug %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Post</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a quote in your `<form>` element. Also, where is the error that you mentioned coming from? Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing the quote I am missing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually misread. But why are you doing a POST instead of a DELETE, and adding that `?_method=DELETE` to the URL? How does that reach the correct route?

Comment: I believe Aioros is correct - you need to change your method="POST" to method="DELETE", and I'm not sure what purpose the _method="DELETE" query parameter serves. It looks like it should just be <form action="/blogs/<%= blog.slug %>" method="DELETE">

Comment: I am using method override, that is why the query looks like that.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Ignore my comment then.

Comment: I thought that method="DELETE" was not recognized. That's why I was overriding the post request to delete.

Answer (score 2):

use `blog._slug` instead of `blog.slug.`
Because , mongoose extracts `"id"` as `collections._id`

Answer (score 0):

In the Delete Route, you are passing slug as parameter so instead of using the **blog.slug**.

Use **slug** only. Example:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <a href="/blogs/<%=slug %>" class="btn btn-primary">View Post</a>
  <a href="/blogs/<%=slug%>/edit" class="btn btn-success">Edit Post</a>
  <form action="/blogs/<%=slug %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Post</button>
  </form>
</div>
```